# how i can merge nested array with in a new object with ramda?

Tags: ramda.js

There is an object that holds variables related to the UI.

```js
const data = [
  { color: [{ primary: "#444", secondary: "#dede", light: "#fff" }] },
  { size: [12,14,16,18,20] },
  ...
];
```

I want to make this object a single array like:

```js
const UI = [
    { colorPrimary: "#444" },
    { colorSecondary: "#dede" },
    { colorLight: "#fff" },
    { size0: 12 },
    { size1: 14 },
    { size2: 16 },
    { size3: 18 },
    { size4: 20 },
    ...
];
```

How can I do this with ramda ?

Comment: How would you distinguish between a property like `color`, where you seem to ignore the array holding the data, and one like `size`, where the array indices become part of the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a clean way to do it with the data as supplied because of the reason expressed in my comment:

> How would you distinguish between a property like `color`, where you seem to ignore the array holding the data, and one like `size`, where the array indices become part of the keys?

But with just a minor tweak to your data, to this:

```
const data = [
  { color: { primary: "#444", secondary: "#dede", light: "#fff" } },
  { size: [12,14,16,18,20] },
];
```

It's reasonably straightforward:

```
const initialCap = str => toUpper(head(str)) + tail(str);

const collectProps = pipe(
  map(map(toPairs)),
  apply(merge),
  mapObjIndexed((pairs, key) => map(
    pair => objOf(key + initialCap(pair[0]), pair[1]), pairs
  )),
  values,
  apply(concat)
);

collectProps(data);
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20color%3A%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%23444%22%2C%20secondary%3A%20%22%23dede%22%2C%20light%3A%20%22%23fff%22%20%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20size%3A%20%5B12%2C14%2C16%2C18%2C20%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20initialCap%20%3D%20str%20%3D%3E%20toUpper%28head%28str%29%29%20%2B%20tail%28str%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20collectProps%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20map%28map%28toPairs%29%29%2C%0A%20%20apply%28merge%29%2C%0A%20%20mapObjIndexed%28%28pairs%2C%20key%29%20%3D%3E%20map%28%0A%20%20%20%20pair%20%3D%3E%20objOf%28key%20%2B%20initialCap%28pair%5B0%5D%29%2C%20pair%5B1%5D%29%2C%20pairs%0A%20%20%29%29%2C%0A%20%20values%2C%0A%20%20apply%28concat%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AcollectProps%28data%29%3B%0A)**.

I don't know anything about the source of your data, so I have no idea if this is at all possible for you to manage.  But if you can, this looks like it should work.

Comment: This is really ingenious, Thank you Scott. I can change the UI object to fit it.
Ramda is really life saver. I need to learn more.
Thank you again.